# JanusGraph Pre-Packaged Distribution: Cassandra forking infinite loop leading to timeout

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph

Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476597/janusgraph-pre-packaged-distribution-cassandra-forking-exceeded-timeout) though the title is similar (the result of the issue is the same, but it doesn't stem from the same origin, my Java version being Java 8).

I am using the [Pre-Packaged distribution version 0.6.1](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.6.1) and it was working until very recently. I don't recall having made any changes to the configuration since it worked.

Even using the verbose option, I can't seem to pinpoint the origin of the error as all seems correct until no logs appear anymore until the timeout, as if there was an infinite loop. Additionally, increasing the timeout has yield no result.

Here is a truncated output:

```
Forking Cassandra...
Running `nodetool statusbinary`. 
<TRUNCATE>
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,173 StorageService.java:1536 - JOINING: Finish joining ring
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,193 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='edgestore_lock_')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='txlog')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='janusgraph_ids')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='system_properties')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='graphindex_lock_')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='system_properties_lock_')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='edgestore')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='graphindex')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,194 SecondaryIndexManager.java:512 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='janusgraph', ColumnFamily='systemlog')
INFO  [main] 2022-08-08 09:12:03,221 StorageService.java:2452 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
..................... timeout exceeded (60 seconds)
See /home/<PATH>/Documents/Progs/JanusGraph/janusgraph-full-0.6.1/bin/../logs/cassandra.log for Cassandra log output.
```

Thanks to everyone who will read!

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop intuition was correct!

### Solution (dirty)

Add `-Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy` in the line `` statusbinary="`$BIN/../cassandra/bin/nodetool statusbinary 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n\r'`" `` in the `wait_for_cassandra` method. (Results in `` statusbinary="`$BIN/../cassandra/bin/nodetool -Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy statusbinary 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n\r'`" ``)
This should solve the issue.

### Explanations

In `bin/janusgraph.sh`, the start of Cassandra is handled by the `start` method, which will then wait for the process to be up before moving on to ElasticSearch and JanusGraph. The wait is handled by the `wait_for_cassandra` method.
In this method, there is an infinite loop waiting for `cassandra/bin/nodetool` to return "running", and which does not handle any other case (i.e. errors, no return, ...).

I thus tried the `cassandra/bin/nodetool statusbinary` command on its own. It returned an error `nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - URISyntaxException: 'Malformed IPv6 address at index 7: rmi://[127.0.0.1]:7199'.`.
Searching this error, I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258217/cassandra-nodetool-urisyntaxexception-malformed-ipv6-address-at-index-7) and more importantly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72396677/16521194). (It seems the error may come from an OpenJDK update)
As I failed to find where to add the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` parameter in order to have it as an environment variable, I resorted to directly modify the `bin/janusgraph.sh` file.

If you have any way to do it properly, I'd be glad to know it!